# How to send data over Cellular Network when Wi-Fi is also connected in IOS

Tags: ios, sockets, cellular-network

I am working on an ios app in Which I need to send data always over Cellular Network whether the device is connected to Wi-Fi or not.If Wi-Fi is not connected then everything works well but When Wi-Fi is connected then the data goes through the Wi-Fi channel,which I think is the default channel for data transmission in case it is in connected state.How can I force data to be sent over cellular network when Wi-Fi is also connected and active.

I dont't want to prompt the user to disable the Wi-Fi.

Comment: Not practical answer for the user but at least works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693358/how-to-use-cellular-data-when-connected-wi-fi-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing this on high-level APIs. Based on other similar questions here on stack, you will have to find the `wwan` interface which is normally `'pdp_ip0'` and bind to its address.

You might find some hints [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13164), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721696/ios-check-if-cellular-technology-available-even-if-the-device-is-on-wifi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925724/how-do-i-force-an-ios-app-to-use-3g-instead-of-wifi).

You may want to have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH212-SW5) as well

Hope this helps