# How to use cellular data when connected Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wifi, cellular-network

I'm looking forward to use cellular data when connected Wi-Fi.
Yi dash camera works like this.

Yi camera make Soft AP. 
iOS or Android phone connect the Wi-Fi.
Between YI and Phone, internal network is made, 
generally, phone cannot use the internet.
but, in Yi network, phone can use internet, sns, streaming, and etc.

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (not practical from an app user perspective) is to manually go to the iPhone `Settings`, `Wi-Fi`section and select the desired Wi-Fi hotspot `i`(info).
From there you can change `Configure IP` to be `Manual` instead of `Automatic` and set the `IP Address` to be the same one as in `Automatic` (same for `Subnet Mask`) and **make sure that `Router` is left empty**.

That way, iOS won't try to use the Wi-Fi to connect to internet but use cellular if available.