# How to get realtime information when querying for WiFi and Cellular data connectivity

Tags: ios, wifi, cellular-network

After looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721696/ios-check-if-cellular-technology-available-even-if-the-device-is-on-wifi), I've written the following routine to programmatically determine the connectivity status of Cellular and WiFi data.

The routine I've written works well but the information it returns is delayed by approximately 20 to 40 seconds as compared with the status shown  by the WiFi and Cellular connectivity icons at the top of the device's screen.

Here's the code:

```
- (PSTR) isLinkedToTypeCom: (PSTR) reqTypCom andTypeFam: (int) reqTypFam
    //...reqTypCom = "pdp_ip0" or "en0"    aka (cell or WiFi)
    //   reqTypFam = AF_INET or AF_INET6   aka ("IPv4" or IPv6")
    //
    //...derived from from Stack Overflow:
    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721696/ios-check-if-cellular-technology-available-even-if-the-device-is-on-wifi
    //...returns an ip address string if both the reqTypCom and the reqTypFam are
    //   matched and the entry is active.  otherwise, it will return NULLSTR.
       {
       struct ifaddrs * pAddrs;
       struct ifaddrs * pAddr;
       NSString         ipAdr = NULLSTR;

       if ( getifaddrs( &pAddrs ) == 0 )
          {
          pAddr = pAddrs;

          while( pAddr != NULL )
             {
             NSString * curTypCom = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: pAddr->ifa_name ];

             if ( [curTypCom isEqualToString: reqTypCom] )
                {
                sa_family_t curTypFam = pAddr->ifa_addr->sa_family;
                bool         isActive = pAddr->ifa_flags & IFF_UP;

                if ( curTypFam == reqTypFam && isActive == true )
                   {
                   if ( reqTypFam == AF_INET )
                      {
                      ipAdr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                               inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)pAddr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                      break;
                      }

                   if ( reqTypFam == AF_INET6 )
                      {
                      char tmp[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

                      inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)pAddr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), tmp, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                      ipAdr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: tmp];
                      break;;
                      }
                   }
                }
             pAddr = pAddr->ifa_next;
             }
          freeifaddrs(pAddrs);
          }

       return( ipAdr );
       }
```

My question: is there something I can do, programmatically, to get the information I want without waiting 20 to 40 seconds?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html  Have a look at this - this is what I use to check for connection status and its pretty instantaneous. If nothing else it could give some insight in to getting your own code working as intended. (for swift I used https://github.com/ooper-shlab/Reachability-Swift )

Comment: Hasn't the latest Apple version of Reachability removed the ability to detect connectivity via WiFi?

Comment: I just tested my app turning wifi on and off and it responded correctly (airplane mode then enabling wifi also worked)

Comment: Yes, I've just been discovering the same.  They removed something to do with WiFi but it was not the default reporting.  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my code here so it now deals with both IPv4 and IPv6 correctly.

Comment: @solenoid I'm also using Reachability now as well - thanks.  If both WiFi and Cellular Data are active, then Reachability returns ReachableViaWiFi.  If onlyCellular Data is active, then it returns ReachableViaWWAN.  If neither is active, then it returns notReachable.  And it returns all this immediately.

But, for readers, my original question still remains.  Is is possible to get the routine I've written to return valid results immediately without the 20 to 40 second delay.

Comment: @creker given that you wrote about this over on SO 31721696, would you have any comments here about why the delay and if anything can be done about it?  Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: off hand do you know which call it is hanging at?

Comment: @solenoid Not hanging.  My calls complete with no delays. I suspect that the data in the table I'm interrogating is only being updated by some background process ever 30 seconds or so.  I've read the man page on getifaddrs() but I'm not seeing any references to how frequently it is updated nor if one can initiate a manual update.